# How to do Integration Testing with Spring REST Docs?

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, asciidoctor, spring-restdocs

I hava a multi module project that runs three web servers. There is one server that is proxying the requests for the other two servers.

I want to do integration testing: When the whole application is running I want to run HTTP requests and check if the responses are correct. I want to run the same tests as i use for unit-testing but with a different port because the proxying should be tested too.

? **How can I tell Spring that I want to run the tests without starting the applications? They are already started. I just want to send requests and check the response.**

---

I have unit-tests that generate `http-request.adoc` and `http-response.adoc` snippets that I use in my asciidoctor API documentation.

Example for http-request.adoc:

```
GET /api?system=one&todo=123 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
```

Example for http-response.adoc:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 111
{"one":"123","two":abc,"three":"543","four":"789"}
```

I use the script parameter: `-Pintegration=true` to switch from unit-test mode to integration-test mode:

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties[integration] == 'true' ? true : false }")
private boolean integrationTest;
```

? **When I do integration testing I don't want to have `Host: localhost:8080` in the request but the host and port of the running
    proxy application (that would be localhost:8030 at the moment). How
    do I achieve this?**

---

*The code I use so far*
Abstract test class. The tests of the modules extend this class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class RestDocsTestGlobal {

 @Rule
 public JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("build/docs/generated-snippets");

 @Autowired
 private WebApplicationContext context;

 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 /*
  * Run unit- or integration-tests?
  * Add "script parameter": "-Pintegration=true" to enable integration tests.
  * Add "script parameter": "-Pintegration=false" to disable integration tests.
  * If the integration tests are enabled they replace the unit tests.
  */
 @Value("#{ systemProperties[integration] == 'true' ? true : false }")
 private boolean integrationTest;

 // "uri" gets the content of "integration" if we run integration tests
 String uri = "/api?";
 String folder = "unit-test";
 String integration = "http://localhost:8030/api?system=x&";
 String integrationTestFolder = "integration-test";

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
  // Run unit- or integration-tests?
  if(integrationTest){
   uri = getIntegration();
   folder = getIntegrationTestFolder();
   System.out.println("Performing integration tests");
  }else{
   System.out.println("Not performing integration tests");
  }

  System.out.println("First part of the URI: "+uri);
  System.out.println("Test documentation folder: "+folder);

  this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
    .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation))
    .build();
 }

 @Test
 public void smokeTest() throws Exception {
  this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get(getUri()).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andDo(document(getFolder()+"/smoke-test"));
 }

 @Test
 public void statusTest() throws Exception {
  this.mockMvc.perform(RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get(getUri()+"todo=123").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.three").value("543"))
    .andDo(MockMvcRestDocumentation.document(getFolder()+"/status-test"));
 }

 public String getUri() {
  return uri;
 }

 public String getFolder() {
  return folder;
 }

 public String getIntegration() {
  return integration;
 }

 public String getIntegrationTestFolder() {
  return integrationTestFolder;
 }
}
```

That the proxy module knows to where to send the requests we override the URL in the specific test implementation of every module. Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
// Todo: Make sure that the configured port is used for integration testing.
// We want to have the correct port appear in the RestDocs documentation.
// I tried something like this but it didn't work:
// @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
// @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppRun.class)
public class RestDocsTest extends RestDocsTestGlobal {

 String integration = "http://localhost:8030/api?system=one&";

 @Override public String getIntegration() {
  return integration;
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to send actual HTTP requests through your proxy, then you'll have to stop using `@SpringBootTest` and `MockMvc`. You'll need to use REST Docs' support for REST Assured instead.

Comment: It looks like this is the solution ;) You might want to post this as an answer that I can accept it as such.